# Display container based on Time of Day

Tags: amp-html

Is it possible to display/hide a container based on the time of Day (server time) in AMP?

This will be in the header of the page which will be cached, so I won't be able to do this on the backend.

Any tips appreciated.

Comment: can you make a file which return value according to time like https://ampbyexample.com/json/examples.json

Comment: I believe the only way you could do this right now would be to use the `amp-list` component to feed in a JSON file containing the current time that isn't cached on your server. There is a new AMP component in the works which looks like it will solve a number of these problems called `amp-date-display`. https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/10837